# Sudoku: Selection image does not appear

Tags: java, imageicon, sudoku

I am building a Sudoku game. I have drawn a grid so far and programmed the selection of a field, but my chosen picture for selection does not appear. My Class for the selector is:

```
package com.brendenbunker;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Selection {

public JLabel boxSelected;
public ImageIcon selected;
int x, y;

public Selection(){

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    selected = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Selected.png"));

    boxSelected = new JLabel("");
    boxSelected.setIcon(selected);
    boxSelected.setBounds((x * (selected.getIconWidth() + 4) + (x / 3) * 4) + 4, (y * (selected.getIconWidth() + 4) + (y / 3) * 4) + 4, selected.getIconWidth(), selected.getIconHeight());
}

public Selection(int x, int y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    selected = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Selected.png"));

    boxSelected = new JLabel("");
    boxSelected.setIcon(selected);
    boxSelected.setBounds((x * (selected.getIconWidth() + 4) + (x / 3) * 4) + 4, (y * (selected.getIconWidth() + 4) + (y / 3) * 4) + 4, selected.getIconWidth(), selected.getIconHeight());
}

public void setNewSelection(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    boxSelected.setBounds((x * (selected.getIconWidth() + 4) + (x / 3) * 4) + 4, (y * (selected.getIconWidth() + 4) + (y / 3) * 4) + 4, selected.getIconWidth(), selected.getIconHeight());
}
}
```

The code which displays everything is:

```
package com.brendenbunker;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ScreenGenerator extends JFrame{

//Intro Components
//JLabel temp;
JLabel[] gridLabel, numbLabel, numbBackLabel;
JLabel[][] numbDisp;
ImageIcon gridPic, numbPic, numbBackPic;
Rectangle[][] boxArea;
Selection selection;
Random random;
//intro Vars


public ScreenGenerator() {

    setLayout(null);

    random = new Random();
    selection = new Selection();
    gridPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Grid_Unified.png"));
    numbBackPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Square.png"));
    gridLabel = new JLabel[9];
    numbLabel = new JLabel[9];
    numbBackLabel = new JLabel[9];
    boxArea = new Rectangle[9][9];
    numbDisp = new JLabel[9][9];

    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        gridLabel[i] = new JLabel("");
            gridLabel[i].setBounds(((i+1)%3)*gridPic.getIconWidth(),Math.round(i/3)*gridPic.getIconHeight(),gridPic.getIconWidth(),gridPic.getIconHeight());
        numbBackLabel[i] = new JLabel("");
        numbBackLabel[i].setBounds(i*numbBackPic.getIconWidth()+1,gridPic.getIconHeight()*3,numbBackPic.getIconWidth(),numbBackPic.getIconHeight());
        numbLabel[i] = new JLabel("");
        numbLabel[i].setBounds(i*numbBackPic.getIconWidth(),gridPic.getIconHeight()*3,numbBackPic.getIconWidth(),numbBackPic.getIconHeight());
        for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
            numbDisp[i][j] = new JLabel("");
            numbDisp[i][j].setBounds((j * (selection.selected.getIconWidth() + 4) + (j / 3) * 4) + 4, (i * (selection.selected.getIconWidth() + 4) + (i / 3) * 4) + 4, selection.selected.getIconWidth(), selection.selected.getIconHeight());
            boxArea[j][i] = new Rectangle((j*(selection.selected.getIconWidth()+4)+(j/3)*4)+4,(i*(selection.selected.getIconWidth()+4)+(i/3)*4)+4,selection.selected.getIconWidth(),selection.selected.getIconHeight());

            add(numbDisp[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {

        numbPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/numb_" + (i+1) + ".png"));
        numbLabel[i].setIcon(numbPic);
        gridLabel[i].setIcon(gridPic);
        numbBackLabel[i].setIcon(numbBackPic);

        add(selection.boxSelected);
        add(gridLabel[i]);
        add(numbLabel[i]);
        add(numbBackLabel[i]);

    }

    setBoxNumb(random.nextInt(9)+1,random.nextInt(9)+1,random.nextInt(9)+1);
    selection.setNewSelection(1,2);

}

public void setBoxNumb(int x, int y, int numb){

    numbPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/numb_" + numb + ".png"));
    numbDisp[x - 1][y - 1].setIcon(numbPic);

}
}
```

So what I am trying to ask is why the image I want to be displayed if a field is selected does not appear ? Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What help do you need? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Why don't u paint on a  `JPanel`?

Comment: I am new, I will look into this for the future. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Better explaining and cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that the layout layers are backwards to what i would expect. The Label you add first will always stay on top. That label won't be drawn over by JComponents add after the original is on. So basically, the earlier in the code you add a component to a JFrame, the Higher the priority that Component has.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to simplify your program down to the simplest one that reproduces the problem. You may discover the problem in the process, but if not, you'll have a clear example of it that's easy to understand.
2. Single step through your program to see if it's behaving as you expect.
3. Add logging to your program to see if it's behaving as you expect.

If you encounter any *specific* issues, feel free to ask a specific question. But right now, you're basically asking "how do I debug a program?"